# Remove p tag using jquery without deleting content

Tags: jquery, html

My situation is like this

```
<p><img src="/media/118711/banner.jpg" width="344" height="113" alt="Banner"></p>
```

I want to delete the p tag using jquery but I do not need to delete content(image). Any one please can help me?

Comment: you never wandered what are the clickable elements beside answers and questions? I cannot believe it.

Comment: @Topener :i think you are mistaken i have only asked six questions and have marked 3 of them as right

Comment: Sorry, confused them with your answers. None of them are marked as right. You'll have to click the check icon, not the arrow: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1177753/athul-ks?tab=questions

Comment: @Topener: sorry from my part too i was unaware of the check icon part

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do it...

```
$('p > *').unwrap();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vm57t/).

Comment: +1 for the concise answer and for pointing me to new learning material (unwrap???). Thanks

Comment: @tymie it selects all direct children and *unwraps* them from their container element, which is the `p`.

Answer (score 6):

Selector `$('p > *')` works only when content of `p` is another tag. If it contains only text, then this selector doesn't hit it. This works for me:

```
$("p").each(function() { 
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});
```